# Vários termos na expressão regular

Tags: regex

Preciso fazer uma busca de algumas palavras específicas em um texto. Estou usando ER para isso. Porém, como preciso buscar mais de uma palavra, em alguns casos o resultado é insatisfatório. Abaixo a ER que estou tentando utilizar (necessito buscar outras palavras, além das que estão abaixo):

```
(; Réu:|=>; Requerido:|=>; Requerido\(s\):|=>)
```

Qual a maneira correta de proceder neste caso? Vale lembrar que com o tempo pode aumentar o número de termos a serem procurados.

Comment: Quais os termos a serem procurados na expressão `(; Réu:|=>; Requerido:|=>; Requerido\(s\):|=>)`?

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho essa é a expressão regular. Preciso buscar estes termos dentro do texto.

Comment: Precisa buscar `Réu:`, `Requerido:` e `Requerido(s):`? Pode editar seu post com um texto completo de exemplo? Outra coisa, vai precisar encontrar o conteúdo até que ponto do texto (até um parágrafo, por exemplo)?

Comment: O texto é um excerto do Diário Oficial, geralmente bem grande. Os termos estão "soltos" no texto, não há um padrão. Por isso, inclusive, que o número de termos pode aumentar com o tempo. Preciso encontrar os termos no texto inteiro. Os termos ocorrem diversas vezes no texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Danilo**, a melhor solução nos regex que buscam múltiplas palavras (strings, etc) é o **`Quantificador Progressivo`** (Possessive Quantifiers), em outras palavras, o `[^"]*`.

**IMPORTANTE**

O `pattern` abaixo encontra TODAS as ocorrências. A visualização dos resultados (em forma de `array`, por exemplo) vai **DEPENDER DA SUA LINGUAGEM DE PROGRAMAÇÃO**.

Exemplo de aplicação em `PHP` com a função `preg_match_all` que retorna TODOS os resultados em forma de `array`:

```
<?php

    $pattern = "/[^\"]*considerando|trabalho|social|providê2ncias|Réu:|Requerido:|Requerido\\(s\\):/"; 

    $string = "CONSIDERANDO o poder constitucional conferido ao Ministério\nPúblico de expedir notificação e requisições para instruir procedimentos\nadministrativos de sua competência;\nCONSI2DERANDO que a Constituição Federal dispõe que \"A\nassistência social será prestada a quem dela necessitar, independentemente\nde contribuição à. Requerido(s): seguridade social, e tem por objetivos: I - a\nproteção à família, à maternidade, à infância, à adolescência e à velhice;\nII - o amparo às crianças e adolescentes carentes; III - a promoção da\nintegração. Requerido: ao mercado de trabalho:\" e\nCONSI2DERANDO os elementos. Réu: contidos no Relatório de Auditoria\nda Controladoria-Geral Réu: da União nos itens 5.1.1.; 5.1.2.; 5.1.3.;\n5.1.6.; 5.1.7.; 5.1.8.; 5.1.10. 5.2.1.; 5.2.2.; 5.2.3.; 5.3.2.; 5.3.5. e 5.3.9;\n(Ministério do. Réu: Desenvolvimento Social e combate à Fome)\nRESOLVE:\nINSTAURAR o presente PROCEDIMENTO PREPARATÓRIO\nNº 03/2015, objetivando apurar as irregularidades apontadas no Relatório\nde Auditoria da Controladoria-Geral da União nos itens 5.1.1.; 5.1.2.; 5.1.3.;\n5.1.6.; 5.1.7.; 5.1.8.; 5.1.10. 5.2.1.; 5.2.2.; 5.2.3.; 5.3.2.; 5.3.5. e 5.3.9;\ndeterminando, desde já, que sejam adotadas as seguintes providências."; 

    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $resultado, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    die(print_r($resultado));

?>
```

[**DEMO USANDO PHP**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/p207-v3g1)

Você deve encontrar a função correspondente na sua linguagem preferida.

**Pattern**

**`[^"]*considerando|trabalho|social|providências|Réu:|Requerido:|Requerido\(s\):`**

**Texto**

```
CONSIDERANDO o poder constitucional conferido ao Ministério
Público de expedir notificação e requisições para instruir procedimentos
administrativos de sua competência;
CONSI2DERANDO que a Constituição Federal dispõe que "A
assistência social será prestada a quem dela necessitar, independentemente
de contribuição à. Requerido(s): seguridade social, e tem por objetivos: I - a
proteção à família, à maternidade, à infância, à adolescência e à velhice;
II - o amparo às crianças e adolescentes carentes; III - a promoção da
integração. Requerido: ao mercado de trabalho:" e
CONSI2DERANDO os elementos. Réu: contidos no Relatório de Auditoria
da Controladoria-Geral Réu: da União nos itens 5.1.1.; 5.1.2.; 5.1.3.;
5.1.6.; 5.1.7.; 5.1.8.; 5.1.10. 5.2.1.; 5.2.2.; 5.2.3.; 5.3.2.; 5.3.5. e 5.3.9;
(Ministério do. Réu: Desenvolvimento Social e combate à Fome)
RESOLVE:
INSTAURAR o presente PROCEDIMENTO PREPARATÓRIO
Nº 03/2015, objetivando apurar as irregularidades apontadas no Relatório
de Auditoria da Controladoria-Geral da União nos itens 5.1.1.; 5.1.2.; 5.1.3.;
5.1.6.; 5.1.7.; 5.1.8.; 5.1.10. 5.2.1.; 5.2.2.; 5.2.3.; 5.3.2.; 5.3.5. e 5.3.9;
determinando, desde já, que sejam adotadas as seguintes providências.
```

[**Demo Regex 101**](https://regex101.com/r/zT4rT0/1)

Comment: Executei seu demo e não encontrou todas as palavras, apenas 1 ocorrência. O que pode ser? De toda forma, grato por sua colaboração.

Comment: @DaniloMiguel, creio ter havido um equívoco da sua parte...o pattern acima encontra SIM todos os resultados, mas a exibição (o retorno) (ex.: `array`) deles irá depender da linguagem que você utiliza. Veja minha resposta acima, coloquei um [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/p207-v3g1) e explicação em `PHP`.

Comment: Perfeito! Estou testando e adaptando à minha realidade. Obrigado!

Comment: haha ótimo! às ordens!